# Where is profile signing information stored on the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

Edge and Chrome allow users to log in to a profile, once you are logged no questions are asked anymore and the users get logged automatically on browser start.

Where is the information stored in Windows? In the registry? In cookies? In the filesystem?

I am trying to copy this information to another computer to get automatically signed to see if it works. I am admin on all the computers involved.

**INFORMATION STORAGES I FOUND UP TO KNOW:**

Equipo\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge
Equipo\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data

I copied the three elements from both installations but even when Edge sees the new profiles they appear as not logged. Where could be the log information stored?

Comment: I doubt the information is stored in the registry since Chromium is cross platform

Comment: Edge adds its own layer on top of Chromium and the number of profiles, UIDs, path to folders of the profiles, etc is stored into Equipo\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge